# How to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.FeatureLayer' in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, interface, casting, esri

Private Function GetRaster(ByRef sLayerLocation As String) As ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.FeatureLayer

```
    Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim pWsFact As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspaceFactory
    Dim pRasterWs As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IRasterWorkspace2

    Dim pRasterDataset As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IRasterDataset
    Dim pRaster As ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IRaster
    Dim pRasterLayer As ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IRasterLayer




    sFolder = fso.GetParentFolderName(sLayerLocation)
    sFile = fso.GetFileName(sLayerLocation)
    Try
        'Open the workspace
        pWsFact = New ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesRaster.RasterWorkspaceFactory
        pRasterWs = pWsFact.OpenFromFile(sFolder, 0)

        'Open the raster dataset
        pRasterDataset = pRasterWs.OpenRasterDataset(sFile)
        pRasterLayer = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.RasterLayer

        pRasterLayer.CreateFromDataset(pRasterDataset)
        pRaster = pRasterLayer.Raster
        **GetRaster = pRaster;** 

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

In above code snippet while trying to assign pRaster to GetRaster the code statement is throwing exception "Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.FeatureLayer" . I tried casting also but that too not working. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raster layers don't implement IFeatureLayer interface. Except raster catalog layers I think. 
Your function should return IRasterLayer or IRaster.